# How to add excel sheet cell comments in R

Tags: r, excel

I am currently cleaning survey data in R. The output will be an excel sheet. I am currently using this comment code to have comments appear in the top row of the excel sheet to explain variable names. An example of this code is: comment(ExitClean$Q1a_1)<-c("name"). While the code runs, it does not consistently create comments in the final excel sheet output. Is there a more updated package or code to use to ensure that these comments appear in the output?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `comment` function - what package are you using? There several common packages for working with Excel sheets, `writexl`, `openxlsx`, `xlsx`, ...

Comment: I am using readxl would you recommend trying the other packages?

Comment: Yeah, if it's not working for you definitely try others. `writexl` is pretty new. I don't know if it lets you add comments. `openxlsx` has been around quite a while. You need to install Java to use it, which gives a lot of people problems, but if you can get it to work I think it's quite fully featured.

Answer (score 0):

To add a comment in a cell, you can consider the following approach. This approach only works on Windows.

```
library(RDCOMClient)

dir_Path <- "D:\\"
excel_File <- "test_Res.xlsx"
path_Excel_File <- paste0(dir_Path, excel_File)

xlApp <- COMCreate("Excel.Application")
xlApp[["Visible"]] <- TRUE
xlWbk <- xlApp$Workbooks()$Open(path_Excel_File)
Sheets <- xlWbk$Sheets() 
Sheets[[1]]$Cells(1,1)$AddComment("Hi, it is a good calculation!")
```